# How to make two lists, one with even numbers and one with odd numbers, in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a problem.

We have one unsorted list:

```
(1 4 5 3 6 7)
```

Can you help me make 2 lists?

One odd numbered, increasing list:

```
(1 3 5 7)
```

and the other even numbered, decreasing list:

```
(6 4)
```

Don't use sort!

I'm trying in scheme. But in prolog I don't know how to make it.

Here:

```
   (define (split lst)
  (let loop ((a '()) (b  '()) (lst lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        (values a (reverse b))
        (let ((cur (car lst)))
          (if (odd? cur)
              (loop (cons cur a) b (cdr lst))
              (loop a (cons cur b ) (cdr lst))
              )))
   )
  )
(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14))
```

Comment: Can you share with us something you tried?

Comment: I'm new in prolog. please help me. I don't good in prolog

Comment: Are you sure you need Prolog and not Common Lisp? Your lists are in Lisp notation, not in Prolog notation.

Comment: I compelled to make it in prolog.

Comment: Have you worked through any online Prolog tutorials? Read any Prolog books? You need to start there and get the basics down (how to write a list, simple list recursion predicates, etc) before attempting a problem like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to start with, we can just separate the evens from the odds pretty easily like this:

```
separate_even_odd([], [], []).
separate_even_odd([X|Xs], [X|Even], Odd) :-
  0 is X mod 2,
  separate_even_odd(Xs, Even, Odd).
separate_even_odd([X|Xs], Even, [X|Odd]) :-
  1 is X mod 2,
  separate_even_odd(Xs, Even, Odd).
```

This isn't terribly efficient—a tail recursive version wouldn't be much harder, and it would be a lot more efficient with a conditional expression, but this seems like a pretty straight-forward way to start. This of course doesn't do exactly what you want:

```
?- separate_even_odd([1,4,5,3,6,7], X, Y).
X = [4, 6],
Y = [1, 5, 3, 7]
```

Since we can't sort, we need to maintain a sorted list. The base case lists are sorted by virtue of being empty, so we just need to come up with a way to insert a value into a sorted list, maintaining the sort property. This isn't very hard in one case or another:

```
insert_into_sorted_list(X, [], [X]).
insert_into_sorted_list(X, [Y|Ys], [X, Y|Ys]) :-
  X =< Y.
insert_into_sorted_list(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]) :-
  X > Y,
  insert_into_sorted_list(X, Ys, Zs).
```

Again, this is not particularly efficient for basically the same reasons. An obvious next step would be to copy and paste and change the direction, giving it a different name, but this is Prolog, we can pass the operator we want to use and invoke it with `call/2` instead.

```
insert_into_sorted_list(_,  X, [],     [X]).
insert_into_sorted_list(Op, X, [Y|Ys], Result) :-
  (   call(Op, X, Y) ->
      Result = [X, Y|Ys]
  ;   insert_into_sorted_list(Op, X, Ys, Zs),
      Result = [Y|Zs]
  ).
```

You can see that it works:

```
?- insert_into_sorted_list(=<, 8, [1,2,4,5,6], X).
X = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8] 

?- insert_into_sorted_list(>, 8, [6,5,4,3,2,1], X).
X = [8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

?- insert_into_sorted_list(<, 8, [6,5,4,3,2,1], X).
X = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8] ;
false.

?- insert_into_sorted_list(<, 0, [1,2,4,5,6], X).
X = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6].

?- insert_into_sorted_list(<, 3, [1,2,4,5,6], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
```

I suspect you can now see what's coming: tying together `insert_into_sorted_list/4` and `separate_odd_even/3`:

```
separate_even_odd([], [], []).
separate_even_odd([X|Xs], Even, Odd) :-
    separate_even_odd(Xs, Even0, Odd0),
    (   0 is X mod 2 ->
        insert_into_sorted_list(>, X, Even0, Even),
        Odd = Odd0
    ;   insert_into_sorted_list(<, X, Odd0, Odd),
        Even = Even0
    ).
```

Check it out, it works:

```
?- separate_even_odd([1,4,5,3,6,7], Even, Odd).
Even = [6, 4],
Odd = [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean a tail recursive and how is it different from recursive? Your solution is recursive, isn't it?

Comment: @AdrianMann A function is tail recursive if the recursive call is the last thing the function does. It's an important subcategory of recursive functions because they can be implemented very efficiently, essentially as a goto, and many languages (including modern Prolog implementations) will notice tail recursion and optimize it.