# Generate List then Split into Two in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I am a complete amateur on Prolog so my question might be very basic. I want to automatically generate a list from 1 to N, then split it into even and odd, from just one integer input (so I don't input the list manually). Let's say I input 5, then the result should be like this:
X = [1,3,5]
Y = [2,4]
Doesn't matter which one is X, which one is Y.

How should I tackle this problem?

I know the built-in function to generate list is `numlist(1,5,L).`
I also found an answer on how to split the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713692/how-to-make-two-lists-one-with-even-numbers-and-one-with-odd-numbers-in-prolog)

I tried to combine those two like this
`separate_even_odd(N) :- numlist(1,N,L), separate_even_odd(L, X, Y).`
Then call the function `separate_even_odd(5).`

All i got is **True**.

Ultimately I want to append the odd list to the even list but let's put that on another story. For now, I just want it splitted.

Comment: "*the built-in function to generate list is `numlist(1,5,L).`*" - see what `L` is doing there. "*Then call the function `separate_even_odd(5).` All i got is True.*" - see that you have no `L` or similar for it to use to give you any other results.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler you're right. That point is actually the most important thing I have learned from this question and the answers. I am glad I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWI-Prolog has a library predicate [partition](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=partition/4)/4 that seems it's done to fulfill your needs:

```
separate_even_odd(Integers, Even, Odd) :-
  partition(integer_is_even, Integers, Even, Odd).
integer_is_even(I) :- I mod 2 =:= 0.
```

Instead of providing the service predicate `integer_is_even`/1, we could as well use the lambda library([yall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)):

```
separate_even_odd(Integers, Even, Odd) :-
  partition([I] >> (I mod 2 =:= 0), Integers, Even, Odd).
```

and we get

```
?- numlist(1,5,L), separate_even_odd(L, Even, Odd).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Even = [2, 4],
Odd = [1, 3,
```

Just to illustrate some of the unusual constructs of Prolog (unification and if/then/else), take a look at a simple implementation, in procedural style, without library predicates:

```
list_with_separate_even_odd(IntegerLow, IntegerHigh, Even, Odd) :-
    (   IntegerLow > IntegerHigh
    ->  Even = [], Odd = []
    ;   (   IntegerLow mod 2 =:= 0
        ->  Even = [IntegerLow|RestEven], Odd = RestOdd
        ;   Even = RestEven, Odd = [IntegerLow|RestOdd]
        ),
        LowSucc is IntegerLow + 1,
        list_with_separate_even_odd(LowSucc, IntegerHigh, RestEven, RestOdd)
    ).
```

Note in particular how [=](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2)/2 performs *unification*, not assigment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method, with an introduction to *difference lists* due to "Ultimately I want to append the odd list to the even list":

```
between_evens_odds(Upper, Evens, EvensTail, Odds) :-
    integer(Upper),
    Upper @>= 1,
    between_evens_odds_(1, Upper, Evens, EvensTail, Odds).

between_evens_odds_(Upto, Upper, Evens, EvensTail, Odds) :-
    compare(Comp, Upper, Upto),
    between_evens_odds_comp_(Comp, Upto, Upper, Evens, EvensTail, Odds).

between_evens_odds_comp_(<, _Upto, _Upper, EvensTail, EvensTail, []).
% Started with 1, so final number will also be odd
between_evens_odds_comp_(=, Upto, _Upper, EvensTail, EvensTail, [Upto]).
between_evens_odds_comp_(>, Upto, Upper, [Upto1|Evens], EvensTail, [Upto|Odds]) :-
    Upto1 is Upto + 1,
    Upto2 is Upto + 2,
    between_evens_odds_(Upto2, Upper, Evens, EvensTail, Odds).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
% Using 0 as an example - it of course fails
?- between(0, 6, Upper), between_evens_odds(Upper, Ev, EvT, Od).
Upper = 1,
Ev = EvT,
Od = [1] ;
Upper = 2,
Ev = [2|EvT],
Od = [1] ;
Upper = 3,
Ev = [2|EvT],
Od = [1, 3] ;
Upper = 4,
Ev = [2, 4|EvT],
Od = [1, 3] ;
Upper = 5,
Ev = [2, 4|EvT],
Od = [1, 3, 5] ;
Upper = 6,
Ev = [2, 4, 6|EvT],
Od = [1, 3, 5].
```

Here's the magic of *difference lists* - since we've already iterated through the list of Evens to the end, we can grab the *tail* of Evens, rather than iterate through all of Evens yet again using `append`, for performance:

```
?- between_evens_odds(5, Ev, EvT, Od), EvT = Od.
Ev = [2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
EvT = Od, Od = [1, 3, 5].
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient implementation:

```
separate_odd_even(N, Odd, Even) :-
    odd_even_loop(1, N, Odd, Even).

odd_even_loop(M, N, Odd, Even) :-
    Bool is sign(abs(N-M)),              % reify equality between M and N to avoid non-determinism
    odd_even_case(Bool, M, N, Odd, Even).

odd_even_case(0, M, _, [M], []).         % M and N are equal
odd_even_case(1, M, N, [M|Odd], Even) :- % M and N are different
    M1 is M + 1,
    odd_even_loop(M1, N, Even, Odd).
```

Examples:

```
?- separate_odd_even(8, O, E).
O = [1, 3, 5, 7],
E = [2, 4, 6, 8].

?- separate_odd_even(9, O, E).
O = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
E = [2, 4, 6, 8].

?- separate_odd_even(3, [1,3], E).
E = [2].

?- separate_odd_even(3, O, [2]).
O = [1, 3].

?- separate_odd_even(3, [1,3], [2]).
true.

?- separate_odd_even(3, [1,2], [3]).
false.

?- time(separate_odd_even(1000000, O, E)).
% 3,000,001 inferences, 0.313 CPU in 0.312 seconds (100% CPU, 9600003 Lips)
O = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17|...],
E = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18|...].
```

Comment: Don't need `abs`, and is better without, to handle e.g. `separate_odd_even(-1, O, E).`

Comment: Using `compare/3` is faster than `Bool is sign(N-M)`, in swi-prolog.

Comment: @brebs Without using `abs`, you don't really have a generic way to reify equality between two integers, as subtraction would yield three possible results (`0`, `-1` or `+1`) and not just two (`0` or `1`), as expected in predicate `odd_even_case/5` . Anyway, for specific cases, this could work.

Comment: @brebs Analogously, using `compare/3`, you would have `=`, `<` or `>` as possible results and this, in general, could lead to redundancies in a code that only needs to know whether two integers are equal or not. But in this specific case, I agree with you that the use of this predicate can make my code faster than yours.